# How can House member make up votes if they failed to cast the vote when called?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, house-rules

In Oct 29, 2015 House Speaker vote, Rep. Rob Bishop [R-UT] and Rep. Daniel William Lipinski [D-IL] and Rep. Gregory W. Meeks [D-NY] were called but no vote was cast. the voting results only showed Rep. Gregory W. Meeks [D-NY] as not voting.

http://www.c-span.org/video/?328947-1/paul-ryan-elected-speaker-house&start=3041

Comment: We need Congressional Voter ID!

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the first roll call

"THE SPEAKER: THE READING CLERK WILL NOW CALL THE NAMES OF MEMBERS WHO DID NOT ANSWER ON THE FIRST CALL"

After the second attempt

"THE SPEAKER: IF THERE ARE ANY MEMBERS WHO DID NOT ANSWER THE CALL OF THE ROLL, THEY MAY COME TO THE WELL AND VOTE AT THIS TIME."

So they can still answer the call of the roll until the vote ends.